# How do I access data from a joined table in my index.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails 4 app with two models Campus and Stat. Campus has_many stats and Stat belongs_to Campus.

The problem I have is I can the data from my Campus table in my show action, but not in my index action. Here's the relevant code from the controllers.

```
  def index
    @stats = Stat.all
  end

  def show
  end
```

Here's my show.html.erb:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p>
  <strong>Attendance:</strong>
  <%= @stat.attendance %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Salvations:</strong>
  <%= @stat.salvations %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Visitors:</strong>
  <%= @stat.visitors %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Offering:</strong>
  <%= @stat.offering %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Campus:</strong>
  <%= @stat.campus.name %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Date:</strong>
  <%= @stat.date %>
</p>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_stat_path(@stat) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', stats_path %>
```

It's outputs the following:

Attendance: 23

Salvations: 0

Visitors: 3

Offering: 5000.0

Campus: Revelstoke

Date: 2013-07-05

Edit | Back

Here's the relevant portion of my index.html.erb:

```
<% @stats.each do |stat| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= stat.attendance %></td>
    <td><%= stat.salvations %></td>
    <td><%= stat.visitors %></td>
    <td><%= stat.offering %></td>
    <td><%= stat.date %></td>
    <td><%= stat.time %></td>
    <td><%= stat.campus.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', stat %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_stat_path(stat) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', stat, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

The output gives me a undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass for the stat.campus.name

I can't figure out why the difference. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the `@stat.campus.name` in show and `stat.campus` in index. Remove `stat.time` in index and change `stat.campus` to `stat.campus.name` and you have the same output.

Comment: Sorry, my first post was incorrect. With the stat.campus.name in index.html.erb it returns an undefined method error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a `stat` with no `campus` associated to it in your database.

To check witch one is it, you could go to the `rails console` and check the `campus_id` property, printing `Stat.all`,

That can happen if you are adding your stats programmatically, or maybe you added a form without every model property.

If you don't want that to happen you can use `validates` in your model. [Check this link](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence).

Comment: Yes of course that's the problem. (hitting hand to side of head). Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not initialising `@stat` in show action, you could do this with:

```
@stat = Stat.find(params[:id])
```

Second, you have to be sure `@stat` has campus associated with it. But as you are not having problems with index, it seems your stat has campus associated, it means that status has a column `campus_id` which value is a valid id of table `campuses`.

## Update

After reading your comment your stat has not a campus associated, you can show an empty string in these cases with:

```
  <td><%= stat.campus.try(:name) %></td>
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem is not with the show action. That works properly. It's when I call the index action that I have an undefined method error.